# Perl module WWW:RobotRules won't install

Tags: perl

Originally, I wanted to install XML::Parser::Expat module which gave a message Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (LWP::UserAgent) which also when tried to install it give a message about one dependency not OK (WWW::RobotRules); additionally test harness failed.
Now installing WWW::RobotRules will give me:

```
""Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/rules-dbm.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 13 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  12
Files=2, Tests=63,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.02 sys +  0.03 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 1/63 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:840: test_dynamic] Error 255
  GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
```

How can I solve this problem?

Regards,

[Edited]

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 28 Jul 2020 01:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'WWW::RobotRules'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz ok
Configuring G/GA/GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for WWW::RobotRules
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
cp lib/WWW/RobotRules/AnyDBM_File.pm blib/lib/WWW/RobotRules/AnyDBM_File.pm
cp lib/WWW/RobotRules.pm blib/lib/WWW/RobotRules.pm
Manifying 2 pod documents
  GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for GAAS/WWW-RobotRules-6.02.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/rules-dbm.t .. Failed 1/13 subtests
t/rules.t ...... ok
```

This is verbose to make test

```
t/rules-dbm.t ..
1..13
ok 1
Rules: /aas /per /god /old
ok 2
Rules:
ok 3
No visits: 2
Last visit: 1595923839
Fresh until: 1627459829
ok 4
ok 5
ok 6
Agent-Name: myrobot
ok 7
*** Dump of database ***
|ua-name|       myrobot
www.aas.no:80|vis       3; 1595923839; Tue Jul 28 17:10:39 2020
www.sn.no:80|vis        1; 1595923829; Tue Jul 28 17:10:29 2020
www.aas.no:80|exp       1627459829; Wed Jul 28 17:10:29 2021
******
ok 8
ok 9
ok 10
ok 11
not ok 12
*** Dump of database ***
|ua-name|       MOMSpider
www.sn.no:8080|r2       /bar
www.sn.no:8080|exp      1595923832; Tue Jul 28 17:10:32 2020
www.sn.no:8080|r1       /foo
******
No agent name specified at t/rules-dbm.t line 122.
ok 13
Failed 1/13 subtests
t/rules.t ......
1..50
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
ok 4
ok 5
ok 6
ok 7
ok 8
ok 9
ok 10
ok 11
ok 12
ok 13
ok 14
ok 15
ok 16
ok 17
ok 18
ok 19
ok 20
ok 21
ok 22
ok 23
ok 24
ok 25
ok 26
ok 27
ok 28
ok 29
ok 30
ok 31
ok 32
ok 33
ok 34
ok 35
ok 36
ok 37
ok 38
ok 39
ok 40
ok 41
ok 42
ok 43
ok 44
ok 45
ok 46
ok 47
ok 48
ok 49
ok 50
ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/rules-dbm.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 13 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  12
Files=2, Tests=63,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr  0.03 sys +  0.01 cusr  0.06 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Comment: Please, run the tests in verbose mode so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: I hope the added text is okay. I run the installation as: 
sudo cpan WWW::RobotRules. 
I don't know how to verbose the test!

Comment: Are you sure you need sudo? Are you installing something that will be used by the system and all the users? If not, see [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib).

Comment: To run verbose tests, run the cpan client, in which run `make WWW::RobotRules` and then `look WWW::RobotRules` which will open a shell in which you run `prove -bv`.

Comment: I've added the verbose in the post.
Regards,

Comment: In the look shell, try editing t/rules-dbm.t: on line 102, increase the number in sleep (e.g. to 10) and run the tests again.

Comment: still same message and verbose.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. Let's wait for someone else.

Comment: I don't see anything useful [on cpantesters](https://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/WWW-RobotRules.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=6.02&grade=3). This seems to be a localised problem.

Comment: Will look at this later.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the sleep function is not working. I replaced this line in t/rules-dbm.t to an alternative waiting function.

`sleep(5) to select(undef, undef, undef, 5)`

However, I didn't know the reason. I tried sleep() in a new code and only sleep() would give unlimited waiting time but whaterver seconds I wrote (e.g. 3000000000000) it didn't wait and excuted the following line immediatley. I wish if someone knows the reason to tell me.

Comment: What version of Perl do you run? How did you install it?

Comment: perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi. I think I had it by default.